# Django can't find my environment variable? VIEW_DB_USER not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default value

Tags: django, environment-variables, connect, credentials, decoupling

I am developing an app in django and I pushed it on Heroku.

I want to query my database with SQL in my views.py, so I connect to my database with `connect` method.

When it comes to deploying my app, I obviously want to hide my database credentials.

So I save them in a `.env` file in root directory and use the `config` function to call these variables from my views.py.

However, I run into:

> VIEW_DB_USER not found. Declare it as envvar or define a default
>   value.

(error at `view_db_user = config("VIEW_DB_USER")` )

Here is my views.py:

```
import os 
import django_heroku 
from decouple import config
import dj_database_url

view_db_user = config("VIEW_DB_USER")
view_db_password = config("view_db_password")
view_db_host = config("view_db_host")
view_db_database = config("view_db_database")

mydb = pg2.connect(user=VIEW_DB_USER, password=view_db_password,
                                host=view_db_host, database=view_db_database)
```

Here is my `.env` file:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'credential_1'

VIEW_DB_USER = 'credential_2'
view_db_password = 'credential_3'
view_db_host = 'credential_4'
view_db_database = 'credential_5'
```

From what I see, the problem is that the function `config` is somehow not working properly. But why?

Please note that this does not work both in local and on heroku.

Also note that SECRET_KEY contains a password of another database that perfectly works, being this passwork stored in my `.env` file.

Comment: Are you using `decouple` from this https://github.com/henriquebastos/python-decouple? Maybe you could share your `requirements.txt`. Ah, and could you please share the full error log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED:

First problem was the columns in the `.env` file.
With the following fix, it works perfectly in local, while on Heroku I still got the same error:

```
SECRET_KEY = 'credential_1'

VIEW_DB_USER = credential_2
view_db_password = credential_3
view_db_host = credential_4
view_db_database = credential_5
```

This was because I forgot to add the environment variables in Heroku **Config Vars** section

> https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/my_app_name/settings

See [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/2015/11/26/package-of-the-week-python-decouple.html) at paragraph "deploying to Heroku"